# Can one choose a sufficiently generic path of a.c.s such that only "codimension 1" bubbling occurs?

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology, holomorphic-symplectic, pseudo-holomorphic-curves

Consider a symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$ of dimension $2n$ (closed or open with bounded geometry). Let $L\subset M$ be a compact Lagrangian submanifold (not necessarily connected).
Consider two regular $\omega$-compatible almost complex structures $J_0,J_1$.
Denote by $(\Sigma,j)$ a given Riemann surface with boundary.

(In my specific application ($\Sigma,j_r$) is a cylinder, with $j_r$ an integrable complex structure corresponding to identification with an annulus in $\mathbb C$ of radii $1$ and $r$.)

Let $u_0:(\Sigma,\partial\Sigma) \to (M,L)$ a simple (not multiply covered) $J_0$-holomorphic curve, with boundary on the Lagrangian $L$.

I want to choose a path of compatible almost complex structures (or tame, if impossible to do for compatible ones), $J_t$ between $J_0$ and $J_1$ such that $u_0$ extends to a family of maps $u_t \colon (\Sigma,\partial\Sigma, j_t) \to (M,L,J_t)$ for $t\in[0,t^*)$ and such that if bubbling occurs at time $t^*$ then it is of a type lying on a strata of codimension-1 in the Deligne-Mumford compactifiction.
i.e. either a **single** disc bubble, or a simple degeneration of $j_t$ (in the cylinder example, the radius $r$ going to $\infty$ or $1$, etc'.

What I would like to eliminate is a whole bubble tree popping out the instant we hit $t^*$. I want the bubbles to appear "one by one", which would reduce my analysis to a finite number of options.

Is such thing possible?  if impossible in general dimension, can this be done in $dim M = 4$?
(If possible to do for codimenstion 2 instead of 1, or actually any fixed codimension, this might also help me)

Thank you in advance!